# Is it possible to auto-format code in Visual Studio's Web Essentials

Tags: visual-studio-2013, web-essentials, autoformatting

I would like to have a way to auto-format specific code in Web Essentials to suit our internal design rules. So, for example, when a user types a hex code with lower case letters, it will automatically set all letters in the code to upper case. I've been searching around for a solution to this but I can't seem to find anything or know if it's even possible.

For clarity, I would like to "write" a set of rules (ideally to a file that could be distributed) that people could use to auto-format their code.

In addition to this, is it possible to output a block of code from a smaller, pre-defined string of text. So, for example, instead of writing out:

```
/*------------------------------------*\
 Tables
\*------------------------------------*/
```

the user could write:

```
section Tables
```

and have it output like above.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: For the example of section Tables, why don't you just use Visual Studio Code Snippets?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

JetBrains Resharper is my opinion the best tool for Visual Studio that can help with all of this (and much more). Some find it expensive and might slow down Visual Studio somewhat if you're using an older computer.

https://www.jetbrains.com/resharper/

Comment: I'll look into this. Thank you for your input. Apparently I can't vote up because of reputation, so here you go ^